# Android java.lang.ClassCastException: MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: android-fragments, google-oauth, updates, youtube-data-api, service-accounts

I am trying to get accounts permission (so I can read from the YouTube Data API server), so with **EasyPermissions.requestPermissions** I open a window asking the user for permission which shows the message: *"This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts)"*. When you press OK, it crashes. The LogCat shows the Fatal Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dtek.youtube.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity at  
    pub.devrel.easypermissions.RationaleDialogClickListener.onClick(RationaleDialogClickListener.java:57)
```

And the line 57 in RationaleDialogClickListener.java where the crash occurs is:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((FragmentActivity) mHost, mConfig.permissions, mConfig.requestCode);
```

According to other similar cases, the solution could be simply to change one import library existing in the *RationaleDialogClickListener.java* thus:

From: import **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**;

to: import **android.app.Fragment**;

The problem is that *RationaleDialogClickListener.java* is read only. The lock to change to writable is disabled, and mouse right button doesn't show a change option.
Some say to try and import the java file as a module. But when I try so, it says that the path doesn't exist (My OS is Ubuntu 16.04).
The path is:

/home/barmistias/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/pub.devrel/easypermissions/0.3.0/fbcbfe8a871702db53e5be80e1f2da72c733655d/easypermissions-0.3.0-sources.jar!/pub/devrel/easypermissions/RationaleDialogClickListener.java

This file is part of an external library called:
*pub.devrel/easypermissions/0.3.0*

And finally, the MainActivity where this permission is coded extends a YouTubeBaseActivity. Maybe relevant because other cases were extending Fragment classes. So, any ideas to solve this blockade? Thanks

**P.S.**: Could this be a problem created by a corrupted update of the Android Studio SDK?, because I believe I hadn't this issue with a previous version.

Comment: Did u look into - When does a ClassCastException occurs? Looks like you got a wrong version of FragmentActivity. Its not in the hierarchy tree of MainActivity. Either wrong jar or wrong version of the jar.

Comment: The crash happens when I press OK from the window: "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts)". And then the LogCat points to the casting in the instruction: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions.

Comment: The crash happens when I press OK from the window: "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts)". And then the LogCat points to the casting in the instruction: **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions**. The read-only RationaleDialogClickListener.java file is located in an External Library Directory, outside of the App Directory... How do I check if this file is the wrong one, or if it is outdated, or corrupted, or misplaced, or even if I am correctly oriented to solve the issue?